# I deleted my launcher panel when I just wanted to delete a launcher. How do I start making a new panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

I just want to copy and paste the bit of text that describes the panel in my other user account. Which textfile can I paste that into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transfer your panel settings from one computer to another, do the following:

```
gconftool --dump /apps/panel > panel-settings.xml
```

Then copy `panel-settings.xml` to your other computer and on that run:

```
gconf --load panel-settings.xml
killall gnome-panel
```

Comment: Theoretically there are really good reasons not to select this answer, but for practical purposes, it answered the question I actually asked, so I'm choosing it.

Answer (score 7):

You can reset the panels back to default by writing the following in a terminal:

`gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel && killall gnome-panel`

Answer (score 2):

If you have another panel left, you can select "New Panel" from the context menu. Then you can position it and add your applets again.